# Set delay/sleep/wait In each action perform In nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I want to print each string separately from an array In interval of 5 seconds. but, currently it perform after each seconds.

```
            var interval = 5000;
            var index = 0;
            var users = ['12321', '456455', '45665', '45645']

            function printUser() {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var user = users[index];
                    console.log("Sent To :" + user);
                    index++;
                    if (index < users.length) {
                        printUser();
                    }
                }, interval);
            }

            var when = '00 */1 * * * *';
            var crn = new CronJob(when, function () {

                printUser();

            }, null, true, "GMT");

            crn.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function printUser(index,interval) {
     setTimeout(function () {
         var users = ['12321', '456455', '45665', '45645'];
         var user = users[index];
         console.log("Sent To :" + user);
         index++;
         if (index < users.length) {
              printUser(index,interval);
         }
     }, interval);
 }

 var when = '* */1 * * * *';
 var crn = new CronJob(when, function () {
       printUser(0,5000);
 }, null, true, "GMT");

 crn.start();
```

Comment: Thanx for your response, but i am using cron schedular and it printing user every 1 second instead of 5 seconds, i have update my question details and code also.

Comment: Sorry It was timing set mistake in cron from my side, but still its printing all users at once.